# Receiving 'Expression being assigned must be constant' when it is

Tags: c#, .net, constants

Is there a way to use something like this:

```
private const int MaxTextLength = "Text i want to use".Length;
```

I think it would be more readable and less error prone than using something like:

```
private const int MaxTextLength = 18;
```

Are there any ways to have the length of the text be the source for a constant variable?

Comment: "constant variable"?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
private readonly static int MaxTextLength = "Text i want to use".Length;
```

Comment: Would you care explaining WHY this works? :)

Comment: Because in fact this is not a const, it is a readonly static variable which behaves like a const meaning it cant be changed, but it is not a const.

Comment: In the answer content I meant, that's the first place users will look for it ;)

Answer (score 32):

Use `static readonly` instead of `const`.

Constants have to be compile time constants

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, if you are using the const keyword the value on the right side of the '=' must be a compile-time constant.  Using a "string".length requires .NET code to execute which can only occur when the application is running, not during compile time.

You can consider making the field readonly rather than a const.

Comment: Probably the most useful explanation as it uncovers why this doesn't work when a const.

Answer (score 4):

Does the value need to be a const? Would a static readonly work for your case?

```
private static readonly int MaxTextLength = "Text i want to use".Length;
```

This will allow you to write the code in a similar manner to your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this but how about...

```
private const string MaxText = "Text i want to use.";

private static int MaxTextLength { get { return MaxText.Length; } }
```